# Torsion-free quotient of a globally generated vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a smooth projective surface over the field $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $E$ is globally generated and $N$ is a torsion-free quotient of $E$. Is $N$ also globally generated? I can see that there is a composed surjection $$H^0(E)\otimes O_X\rightarrow N\,.$$
But how do we show that there is a surjection $$H^0(N)\otimes O_X\rightarrow N$$?

Comment: The map $H^0(E)\otimes O_X\to N$ factors through $H^0(N)\otimes O_X$.

Comment: Ah I see that now. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Mohan, can you please kindly explain more why the map factor through $H^0(N)\otimes\mathcal O_X$? Thanks in advance.